# ReferenceError: stopFireworks is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

following problem: I start the fireworks as soon as the highscore is cracked. How can I stop the fireworks again? I tried it with the start the game button, but I get the error that stopFireworks not defined.

Button:

`<button id="start" onclick="stopFireworks()" type=button >Start</button>`

Code:

```
if (score > saved5) {
  saved5 = score; //speichert neuen Highscore, wenn der score größer ist als die gespeicherte variable
  localStorage.setItem('highscore', score); //speichert highscore im browser
  document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = saved5;
  var fireworks = {
    // init fireworks
    init: function() {
      this._addEventListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        return fireworks.resize.apply(fireworks);
      });
      this._addEventListener(window, 'load', function() {
        return fireworks.start.apply(fireworks);
      });
this._addEventListener(btnStart, 'click', function() { return fireworks.stop.apply(fireworks); });
    },


    // add an event listener
    _addEventListener: function(el, name, handler) {
      if (el.addEventListener)
        el.addEventListener(name, handler, false);
      else if (el.attachEvent)
        el.attachEvent('on' + name, handler);
    },


    // start fireworks
    start: function() {
      // init window size
      this.resize();

      // start to move particles
      this._animFn = function() {
        fireworks._move();
      };
      this._lastInterval = this._time();
      requestAnimFrame(this._animFn);

      this._addExplosion();
    },
    stop: function() {
      this._running = false;
      window.clearTimeout();
    },
  })();

function stopFireworks() {
  fireworks.stop();
}
fireworks.start();
}
return saved5;

}
```

Comment: Given the `return saved5;` at the end of your code, I have to imagine that `stopFireworks()` is being declared within another function block, rather than globally.

Comment: So I should write the `stopFireworks()` function outside of saved5?

Comment: It looks like your `init` function is attaching events already. I would get your button as an element and add an event listener in `init`, something like `this._addEventListener(YourButton, 'click', function() { return fireworks.stop.apply(fireworks); });`

Comment: Hm I tried this one, but nothing change. After I click `Start` to play a new game, the firework keeps going during the game.

Comment: Did you define `YourButton` in my example?

Comment: Yep, I define it to start

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that portion I suggested just so I can verify that we're on the same page?

Comment: @TylerRoper Done, I edit it

Comment: `#start` is not how you reference an element in javascript. Try `var btnStart = document.getElementById("start");` and then do `btnStart` instead of `#start`.

Comment: @TylerRoper the firework keep going after pressing start. i dont get it

Comment: Please update the code in your question as you change it so that I can follow along.

Comment: @TylerRoper I updated the code. The Line `var btnStart = document.getElementById("start");`I put after the line `document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = saved5;`because its too much code to edit.